# Iterating over xml files with varying number of nodes

Tags: ruby, xml

My program behaves differently depending on if there is one or more multiple nodes.

```
body["Folder"].count
```

Single node example

```
<Document>
  <Folder>
    <name></name>
    <placemark></placemark>
  </Folder>
</Document>
```

Expected output: 1, actual: 2 
It appears to perform the count on the nodes inside of folder.

Multiple node example

```
<Document>
  <Folder>
    <name></name>
    <placemark></placemark>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
    <name></name>
    <placemark></placemark>
  </Folder>
</Document>
```

Expected output: 2, actual: 2
It counts the Folder nodes, and not the Folder children. 3 Folders gives 3, etc.

What can I do to count the Folder node, and not its children, in the single node example?

Comment: Can you provide a running example or at least some information on what ```body``` actually is?
What XML Library are you using?

Comment: Body is a hash of the document. To parse the file, I'm currently using the crack gem, but I ran into the same issue using Ruby's standard libraries to convert xml to a hash or json.

Comment: So what does the hash look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[mcve]". We need to see the minimum code you wrote that demonstrates the problem. Without that you're making us guess what you wrote. I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to parse and process the XML; It's the de facto standard for Ruby parsing of HTML/XML. The tutorials, documentation, and questions here about using Nokogiri can answer almost any question you'll have about its use.

Answer (score 0):

`crack` gem will put equal tags under the same key as an array. If you try this:

```
require 'crack'

body = Crack::XML.parse("<Document> <Folder><name></name><placemark></placemark></Folder><Folder><name></name><placemark></placemark></Folder></Document>")
```

`body` will be:

```
=> "{\"Document\"=>{\"Folder\"=>[{\"name\"=>nil, \"placemark\"=>nil}, {\"name\"=>nil, \"placemark\"=>nil}]}}"
```

Meaning that `body["Folder"]` is an array with two elements (the two 'Folder' tags) and count will `count`will return `2`.

The same very reason why the number of '' is always the result of count.